# ASUS X550L Windows 10 WiFi

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, asus-laptop, wifi-driver

Lately my **ASUS X550L** Became unable to connect to my AP WiFi or to any other AP, even if it shows the list of available networks. However and to my surprise it still can connect to my Androids Hotspot (**Nexus 5X Android 8.1.0**).

At First I thought that it might be something related to security settings of the AP but even under WEP setting it couldn't connect.

I have **D-Link DSL-2730U AP**